# Select both hyphenated or non-hyphenated version of term with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a python script that finds words/terms in webpages with BeautifulSoup. I want it so that the user puts in either hyphenated or non-hyphenated versions of a term and it will check for both, e.g. "data-driven" also checks "data driven".

If I have this text:

```
Slaying the ‘old school’ bosses with data-driven platforms.

Slaying the ‘old school’ bosses with data driven platforms.
```

And the regular expression:

```
(.+(\W(data((-)|(\s))driven)\W).+)
```

Then it only captures the hyphenated version, not the non-hyphenated version.

How can I modify it to work? I am looking at it on http://regexr.com/

Comment: That expression seems to work in both cases for me.

Comment: Ach - I didn't have "global" selected... you're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern captures both hyphenated and non-hyphenated, so what's the issue? I don't know the reason for your pattern, but it looks over complicated to me. How about this simple one?

```
data[- ]driven
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't have global selected. Also, nice and simpler version thanks.